# ¿How do apply weights to my data frame in r?

Tags: r, weighted

So I want is to apply weights to my observations from my data frame, also I already have an entire column with the weights that I want to apply to my data.

So this how my data frame looks like.

| weight | count |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 67 |
| 7 | 355 |
| 8 | 25 |
| 7 | 2 |

And basically what I want is to weight each value of my COUNT column with the respective weight of my column WEIGHT. For example, the value 67 of  of my column Count should be weighted by 3 and the value of 355 of my column Count should be weighted by 7 and so on.

I try to use this code from the questionr package.

```
wtd.table(data1$count, weights = data1$weight)
```

But this code altered my data frame and end up reducing my 1447 rows to just 172 entries. What I want is to maintain my exact number of entries.

The output that I want, would be something like this. I just want to add another column to my data frame with the weighted values.

| Count | Count applying weights |
| --- | --- |
| 67 | #### |
| 355 | ### |

Comment: What is the final form do you want to achieve?

Comment: Actually I would want to add another column that has the weighted value of my column count, I updated my post to put my expected value above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am still not sure *how* to apply weights to the count data in the way you want.
I just want to show that you can create a new column based on the previous column in a convenient way by using `dplyr`. For example:

```
mydf
#  weight count
# 1      3    67
# 2      7   355
# 3      8    25
# 4      7     2

mydf %>% mutate(weightedCount = weight*count, 
                percentRank = percent_rank(weightedCount), 
                cumDist = cume_dist(weightedCount))

#  weight count weightedCount percentRank cumDist
# 1      3    67           201   0.6666667    0.75
# 2      7   355          2485   1.0000000    1.00
# 3      8    25           200   0.3333333    0.50
# 4      7     2            14   0.0000000    0.25
```

Here, `weightedCount` is multiplication of `weight` and `count`, `percentRank` shows the rank of each data in `weightedCount` and `cumDist` shows cumulative distribution of the data in `weightedCount`.

This is an example. You can create another column and apply other functions in the similar way.